Setting autonumber starting point
How can I set the starting point of an auto number field without additional deployments?
I have an auto number field in production that is referenced in code in multiple places. I need it to start from 1,000,000. I tried redeploying the field and adding the following:
<startingNumber>1000000</startingNumber>
However, this approach isn't working.
I can't change the field type because, as mentioned, the field is referenced in several places. Is there a way to set the starting number without having to comment out the references in one deployment, change the field type to set the auto number, and then do another deployment to remove the comments? This doesn't seem like the best option — there must be a better way, right?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

According to this help article, that does appear to be the only way to reset or restart an autonumber field. I would use caution using an autonumber field for any business critical logic, as they aren't guaranteed to be continuous and can skip number, just as an FYI.
